# Access class name of parameterized type

Tags: java, generics

I have a parameterized class. I would like to get the name of the class represented by the class name. For instance, what I want to do is this:

```
public T foo(){
    System.out.println(T.class.getName());
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3403909/get-generic-type-of-class-at-runtime possible duplicate

Comment: Yes, duplicate, I agree. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java generics don't work that way. If you have any bounds on T, you can access the bounds by querying the type variable definition. E.g.:

```
public class Foo<T extends Bar>{}
```

will let you get at `Bar`, but not at the subtype of `Bar` you are actually using. It doesn't work, sorry.

Read the [Java Generics FAQ](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/JavaGenericsFAQ.html) for more info.

BTW: One common solution to this problem is to pass the subtype of T into your class, e.g.

```
public T foo(Class<? extends T> tType){
    System.out.println(tType.getName());
}
```

I know it's cumbersome, but it's all Java generics allow.

Comment: Actually, you can get what `T` is.  See my answer for how.  (Not sure why it was downvoted!)

Comment: @ziesemer you can only get at bounds that are actually there. If the above T was declared `T extends Something`, you could get at the something part. But if your type variables have no bounds there's nothing to get at.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do it this way, since `T` isn't known at compile time. You could achieve something similar like so:

```
public void foo(T t) {
    System.out.println(t.getClass().getName());
}
```

Note that this takes an instance of `T` and would print out the name of its *dynamic* type.

Whether or not this is a good enough substitute depends on your use case.

Comment: In addition, this gives you the name of the class of `t`, which could be a subclass of the type parameter.

Comment: @StephenC: This is what I meant by "*dynamic* type".

Answer (score 0):

```
public T foo(T t){
    System.out.println(t.getClass().getName());
}
```